# Resizing column size of a table in DB and effecting with the dataTableAdapter on a Dataset.xsd

Tags: c#, database-design, datatable, xsd, datatableadapters

I'm asking about a problem with C# and Visual Studio 2012; I'm trying to resize a column of a table in my database, effect with the `dataTableAdapter` on a `Dataset.xsd`

I'm using `DataTableAdapter` from a stored procedure with a `SELECT` statement to populate a `DataGridView`, reports and many more.

I created the table long time ago, but now there is an a problem with it.

I had to increase the length of a column and I changed the appropriate column length of the `DataTable` also. But it didn't give me the solution. still whenever I `Fill` or `Get` data through that `DataTableAdapter` it response with the previous (original) size of the column.

But when I create a new `DataTable` and redirect my code to the new `DataTableAdapter`, it works.

Why is this happening ?

Because redirecting code to the new `DataTableAdapter` is little bit difficult because I don't know all the places it use in the entire solution.

And also if can please tell me how to add new column to the table and deal with the `DataTableAdapter` with it also.

Thanks and waiting for your reply.

Comment: Isn't  any one bother with same issue and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

after doing small research with my friends , i got an proper way to fix this error.

not even **re-sizing**, but also any other change with the **database Table** or **storedprocedure** you have to reconfigure the **dataTableAdaptor**, unless it just work as , when it was created.

it will continue with major errors or sometimes, it will function incorrectly, even you cant figure out there is an error.

so whenever you do any change  with the **database Table** or **storedprocedure** go to the **dataSet.xsd** , where the dataTable locate and right on the dataTable , then configure it again.

this saved me and worked.